# Python & Kivy: fetching value from another screen to set button on_release value

Tags: python, sqlite, kivy

Okay, so what I'm aiming for is that when you push a button on lets say "anotherScreen", i want to be sent to "Screen 0". Here, depending on a value that is either 0 or 1 fetched from a SQLite database, the button "btn" on screen will either send you to screen1 (if value is 0) or to screen2 if value is not 0 (1). However this rises some errors.

Here's some code to explain it better:

**pythonfile.py**

```
import sql_server_file as app_users
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.app import App

class screen0(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sql_cursor = app_users.AppUsers()
        self.user_id = self.manager.get_screen("anotherScreen").user_id   # <---- This gives 
                                                                      # me an NoneType Error

        self.value = self.sql_cursor.fetch_ids100_done_status(self.user_id)
        if(self.value == 0):
            self.ids["btn"].on_release = "app.root.current = 'screen1'" # <---- This is 
                                          # syntactically wrong, however, how can I do this?

        else:
            self.ids["btn"].on_release = "app.root.current = 'screen2'" # <-- See above

class screen1(Screen):
    pass
class screen2(screen):
    pass
class anotherScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        self.user_id = 0

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class ReturnClass(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(anotherScreen())
        sm.add_widget(screen0())
        sm.add_widget(screen1())
        sm.add_widget(screen2())
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ReturnClass().run()
```

So, I need this to run "automatically" when the screen after "anotherScreen" is entered.

Error raised:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_screen'
```

kivy file could look like this:

**kivyfile.kv**

```
WindowManager:
    anotherScreen:
    screen0:
    screen1:
    screen2:

<anotherScreen>:
    Button:
        text: "get to screen0"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "screen0"

<screen0>:
    Button:
        text: "Get to either screen1 or screen2 depending on value in sqlite-database"

<screen1>:
    Label:
        text: "Screen1"

<screen2>:
    Label:
        text: "Screen2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__init__()` method of `screen0` is called before it is assigned to a `ScreenManager`, so the `self.manager` is `None`. That causes the error you are seeing. The fix is to move that code to a different method that is called after the `ScreenManager` is assigned. A good choice would be an `on_enter()` method that is called automatically when the screen is entered.

Then the `screen0` class can be:

```
class screen0(Screen):
    # no __init__() method needed

    def goto_screen1(self):   # go to screen1
        self.manager.current = 'screen1'

    def goto_screen2(self):   # go to screen2
        self.manager.current = 'screen2'

    def on_enter(self, *args)::   # the new method
        self.sql_cursor = app_users.AppUsers()
        self.user_id = self.manager.get_screen("anotherScreen").user_id

        self.value = self.sql_cursor.fetch_ids100_done_status(self.user_id)
        if(self.value == 0):
            self.ids["btn"].on_release = self.goto_screen1

        else:
            self.ids["btn"].on_release = self.goto_screen2
```

Note that `Screen` classes should have a `name` assigned.

Also, the lines in your `kv`:

```
WindowManager:
    anotherScreen:
    screen0:
    screen1:
    screen2:
```

are redundant (since you build the same widget tree in your `build()` method), and can be removed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, John! Yes, sorry, I just wrote a recap of my problem and forgot the names in the kv-file. I did not know that those lines were redundant, just started to learn kivy! This helps very much, thanks for the answer and I hope you'll have a nice day!

Comment: Note my edited answer with a better solution.

Comment: Hmm, so the on_enter method is called automatically?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the answer in the kivy docs. The answer is obviously yes! Thanks a lot for the answer.